# Half-open intervals

Tags: braces, delimiters

Why the following command is not right:

```
$\left{ [ (1 + 1) ) + V_{K_i} \right}$
```

When compiled, it says:

```
Missing delimiter (. inserted). [Something else: $\left{]
Missing } inserted. [...else: $\left{ [ (1 + 1) ) + V_{K_i} \right]
Missing delimiter (. inserted). [...lse: $\left{ [ (1 + 1) ) + V_{K_i} \right}]
Extra }, or forgotten $. [...lse: $\left{ [ (1 + 1) ) + V_{K_i} \right}]
```

Comment: is this what you want?.   $\left\{ [ (1 + 1) ) + V_{K_i} \right\}$

Comment: You need to use `\left\{` ... `\right\}`, not `\left{` ... `\right}`. Braces have special meaning, but `\{` and `\}` actually *set* braces.

Comment: I observed there is an unpaired [...].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Braces have special meaning in TeX. If you're interested in setting actual braces you need to escape them, as in `\{` and `\}`. So, in your case, use

```
\left\{ ... \right\}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to Latex, but I should have not made such mistakes.

Comment: @Feng don't be too hard on yourself, we have all been there